# Hot swap available by maven wrapper (mvnw)?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I added `spring boot dev tool` dependency in current Spring boot application, but when running the application by `mvnw spring-boot:run` It seems not recognized the change made in Java

I do use Eclipse to make the code change and enable `automatically build.` and refresh my code. So i think the latest .class file should be under `/target` directory

So does `mvnw` supports hot swap at all?

Comment: Why are you using Maven to run your application? I’d recommend launching it in Eclipse instead using `Run As -> Java Application`

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson I kind of have two IDEs making changes to the same project, one is for the front end + backend, the other just the backend (Eclipse for backend debugging). So it is better to have the application running without IDE context.